# Unable to load appssettings.json in maui

Tags: maui

Here i am trying to access the appsettings.json from the  Asssembly but it only shows the default loaded files as if the appssetings.json didn't exist in the same path

````
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()

            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
         builder.Services.AddSingleton<SignalrMessenger>();
         Assembly a =Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using Stream str = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiAppClient.appsettings.json");//null
        var x =Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();//list everything but the appsettings.json {App.xaml, MainPage.Xaml,AppShell.xaml}
        return builder.Build();
    }```

so how do you register the appssetings file?
````

Comment: what's the build action of the file set to?

Comment: @Jason Content...

Comment: You are trying to load it as a resource

Comment: @Jason using it as a resource throws an error when it is building

Comment: https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/

Comment: @Jason this way woked var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
   .Build();

Comment: but the value shows  as null